# Weyl tensor propagation equation and its practical use

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gravitational-waves

There exists a differential equation for the divergence of the Weyl tensor, derived from the (contracted version of) differential Bianchi identity $R_{\mu\nu[\alpha\beta;\gamma]}=0$ and the decomposition of the Riemann tensor. The semicolon stands for the covariant derivative.  The propagation equation has the following form:
\begin{gather}
\label{weylpropagationriccirhs}
    \nabla^{\mu}C_{\,\mu\alpha\beta\gamma} = \nabla_{[\beta}R_{\gamma] \alpha} -\frac{1}{6}\nabla_{[\beta}R\,g_{\gamma]\alpha}.
\end{gather}

If we make use of the Einstein Field Equations, we are getting:

\begin{gather}
    \label{weylpropagationmatter}
    \nabla^{\mu}C_{\,\mu\alpha\beta\gamma} = \kappa \big{(} \nabla_{[\beta}T_{\gamma] \alpha} -\frac{1}{3}\nabla_{[\beta}T\,g_{\gamma]\alpha} \big{)}.
\end{gather}

Since often no mention of this equation is made in standard GR courses, I wonder if the following two sentences are true - and to what extent.

1. In seeking the solutions to the Einstein equations we often implicitly constrain (or even more often - completely determine) the possible Weyl tensors by imposing symmetries and functional dependencies on the metric components.
2. Should some freedom in finding $g_{\alpha\beta}$ remain, solving the Weyl tensor propagation equation with some boundary conditions assumed will determine the metric fully.

I would like to learn about any papers that make use of this equation to find the physical metric $g_{\alpha\beta}$. Specifically, I want to find any example in which using and analyzing this equation is necessary or helpful to establish the desired metric properties and e.x. far-field behaviour.

Comment: The 3+1 formalism in cosmology makes use of Weyl tensor propagation. Actually, for such cases the more relevant quantities involved are the Electric and Magnetic part of Weyl tensor, so one considers propagation of such quantities. See: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9812046v5

Comment: Very interesting! So this concerns exactly this propagation equation contracted with the observer's four-velocity and decomposed into these two parts?

Comment: Not just observer, but wrt any unit time like velocity field